# DOTS 0.50: Multiple Errors when installing Hybrid Renderer

Tags: console, unity-dots

I'll go straight to the point: I'm getting many errors when installing Hybrid Renderer for my DOTS project. I have no idea what to do. I haven't installed any other packages because there were already too many errors with this one. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? Error messages are below.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.entities@0.50.0-preview.24\Unity.Entities.Editor\Unity.InternalAPIEditorBridge.002\ProfilerModules\StructuralChangesProfilerModuleBridge.cs(117,30): error CS0507: 'StructuralChangesProfilerModuleBridge.Clear()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'internal' inherited member 'ProfilerModule.Clear()'

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.entities@0.50.0-preview.24\Unity.Entities.Editor\Unity.InternalAPIEditorBridge.002\ProfilerModules\MemoryProfilerModuleBridge.cs(92,32): error CS0507: 'MemoryProfilerModuleBridge.defaultOrderIndex': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'private protected' inherited member 'ProfilerModule.defaultOrderIndex'

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.entities@0.50.0-preview.24\Unity.Entities.Editor\Unity.InternalAPIEditorBridge.002\ProfilerModules\MemoryProfilerModuleBridge.cs(94,54): error CS0115: 'MemoryProfilerModuleBridge.DetailsViewController': no suitable method found to override

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.entities@0.50.0-preview.24\Unity.Entities.Editor\Unity.InternalAPIEditorBridge.002\ProfilerModules\MemoryProfilerModuleBridge.cs(110,30): error CS0507: 'MemoryProfilerModuleBridge.Update()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'internal' inherited member 'ProfilerModule.Update()'

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.entities@0.50.0-preview.24\Unity.Entities.Editor\Unity.InternalAPIEditorBridge.002\ProfilerModules\MemoryProfilerModuleBridge.cs(117,30): error CS0507: 'MemoryProfilerModuleBridge.Clear()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'internal' inherited member 'ProfilerModule.Clear()'

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.entities@0.50.0-preview.24\Unity.Entities\DefaultWorld.cs(26,25): error CS0117: 'JobsUtility' does not contain a definition for 'ClearSystemIds'

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.entities@0.50.0-preview.24\Unity.Entities\EntityManager.cs(221,29): error CS0117: 'JobsUtility' does not contain a definition for 'PanicFunction'

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.entities@0.50.0-preview.24\Unity.Entities\EntityManager.cs(223,29): error CS0117: 'JobsUtility' does not contain a definition for 'PanicFunction'

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.entities@0.50.0-preview.24\Unity.Entities\SystemDependencySafetyUtility.cs(64,53): error CS0117: 'JobsUtility' does not contain a definition for 'GetSystemIdMappings'

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.entities@0.50.0-preview.24\Unity.Entities\SystemState.cs(416,50): error CS0117: 'JobsUtility' does not contain a definition for 'GetSystemIdCellPtr'
```